# How long do oven elements last under high usage?

Tags: oven

If someone were to use their oven to cook five-hour pot roasts every 2-3 days, how long would the elements last before they would need to be replaced?

Comment: Welcome Keven!  Have you done any research on this question yet?  If so, can you please share your findings?

Comment: Some say many years, some say few. From two reliable sources, TFD's answer being one, if cared for they can last 10-30 years easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In theory the elements could last 10's of years, there is nothing in typical electric element design that limits their life. I would expect modern oven elements to last at least ten years with daily use

They may fail prematurely due to damage (being knocked) in the oven while hot, from surface oxidation due to improper cleaning, or because of slight manufacturing faults